# Reaching an object inside a linkedlist- Java

Tags: java, class, linked-list

I have a linked list of Some_class type I made, in the class, I have created a method to insert and show some data. In the main class, I have created a linkedlist of type Some_class, and I created an object as well. 
I called the object with my Insert method and it's going fine.
then I added the object in the linkedlist as follow:

```
LinkedList <Some_class> myL_L = new LinkedList<Some_class>();
Some_class e1 = new Some_class();
e1.insert_data(); //this is a method I made
myL_L.add(e1); //I added the obj inside the LinkedList
```

I want to reach this object inside the linkedlist, and show its data.
I can use the show_data method I made in the class, but I have a case where I want to show all the elements that are stored in the linkedlist, 
but the " myL_L.get(); " doesn't show the elements.

```
e1.show_data();

myL_L.getLast(); // I can't use this
```

any help please?
thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to get the object out of the list first. `SomeClass e = myList.get(0); e.showData();` (fixed the naming to reflect Java conventions).

Comment: What does `insert_data` do? Also please rename class and methods names to `SomeClass` and `insertData`, it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the `LinkedList`:

```
for(Some_class e : myL_L) {
    e.show_data();
}
```

Or print it using `System.out.println` (given that you've implemented the `toString` method in `Some_class`):

```
System.out.println(myL_L)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to override `toString()` in your `Some_Class` and print it with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myL_L.toArray()));`

Another - iterate over the collection with a `for (Obj obj: collection)` and print each `obj` separately.

BTW: have a quick look at [Java naming convenction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)